# .style of child nodes in d3js

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm trying to make a simple graph with nodes and links. I have "g" elements containing a circle and its text, and links on their own. I have, for example, this bit on code called on a mouseover event:

```
//check if circle is connected to current "viewed" (mouseover-ed) 
//circle via a link referenced by "that" and paint it green if so
circles.filter(function() {
         return d3.select(this).attr("index") == d3.select(that).attr("src");
         }).attr("viewed",1).style("stroke", "green");
                     });
```

This was really a long shot as nodes is the 'g' element container and I wasn't sure what calling .style would do, but to my surprise it did change the color - but only for the text!

Is there a way to make it change the stroke style of the circle as well?

The declaration code:

```
var circles = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class","nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",function(d,i){d.x = getX(i);d.y=getY(i);return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";})
    .attr("name", function(d){return d.name;})
    .attr("viewed",  0)
    .attr("focused", 0)
    .attr("index", function(d, i) {return i;});


circles.append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "white")
   .attr("r", node_radius_wo_pad)
    .on("mouseover", function(){...};


circles.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor","middle")
        .text(function(d){return d.name});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is working is that you haven't explicitly declared a stroke colour for the text and so it inherits what you set for the parent `g` element. To make this work for the circles, you have to select them explicitly:

```
var toChange = circles.filter(function() {
       return d3.select(this).attr("index") == d3.select(that).attr("src");
     });
toChange.attr("viewed", 1);
toChange.selectAll("circle").style("stroke", "green");
toChange.selectAll("text").style("stroke", "green");
```